# How to make a commutative diagram smooth?

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I have drawn the following diagram:

[image]

using the following command:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
  A\ar[rrrr]\ar[rrdd] && && B\ar[lldd] \\
                                       \\
  && C &&
}
\end{document}
```

But this diagram is not smooth, especially the arrow `AC` and `BC`. How can I make it smooth?

Comment: I have a smooth lines compiling your document. How do you compile and what viewer you use?

Comment: It's important to know what TeX system you're using and how you get final output; is it `pdflatex` or `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`? In any case, you seem to have an outdated TeX distribution.

Comment: I have compiled it through 'pdflatex' with 'kile'. I am using 'Document viewer' to view PDF file.

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar You probably suffer from having the very outdated TeX Live 2009 provided by Ubuntu. Try updating to TeX Live 2012.

Answer (score 3):

The diagram is fine. I've compiled your code on MacTeX 2012 with `pdflatex`:

[image]